# How to access map values in GO?

Tags: go

How do I access the map value for the following code? The code snippet is auto generated, so I can't modify it. I have tried `OpType_name[OpType_UNKNOWN]` but I am getting error from the golang compiler.

```
type OpType int32

const (
    OpType_UNKNOWN OpType = 0
    OpType_CREATE OpType = 1
    OpType_DELETE OpType = 3
)

var OpType_name = map[int32]string{
    0: "UNKNOWN",
    1: "CREATE",
    2: "DELETE",
}
var OpType_value = map[string]int32{
    "UNKNOWN": 0,
    "CREATE": 1,
    "DELETE": 2,
}
```

Error:
`cannot use int(api.OpType_UNKNOWN) (type int) as type int32 in map index`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go is very strict on types. Your maps all have keys with typ int32 and you are trying to access them using a value of type OpType. It doesn't matter that OpType is an int32.

You can cast your OpType to int32 and make it work

```
func main() {
  fmt.Println(OpType_name[int32(OpType_UNKNOWN)])
}
```

The comment from @nos is a good way to go, it's probably what you want in this case.

https://play.golang.org/p/dum5GiB3zS

Comment: Alternatively, make the map use OpType instead of int32, `map[OpType]string{`

Comment: I think it worth to do a bit of nit-picking: `OpType` is not `int32`: it only shares the internal representation of the values of its type with `int32`. The crucial point is that `type B A` does not make `B` "inherit" any methods of `A`. This does not matter for `int32`, which does not have methods, but is important to know when dealing with custom types.

Comment: I mean, that's the reason why Go does allow type-conversion from `int32` to `OpType` (the internal representation of the value is the same) but does not allow to assign a value of `OpType` to a receiver of type `int32`: if it would be allowed, the receiver might want to call a method defined for its type but the value passed to it would not have it in its (different) type.